# Wordpress - How do I display posts grouped by custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, while-loop, custom-post-type

I am creating a FAQ page using a custom post type and custom taxonomy. I'm trying to create an unordered list for each taxonomy in order to group the FAQ's. In that unordered list, I want the first listed item to be the taxonomy name and then repeat the second listed item for all the questions in the taxonomy. This is the page I'm working on [link](https://fem.safe2choose.org/faqs).

It's currently duplicating the posts instead of displaying in the rightful taxonomies.

```
                        <?php
                        // get all the categories from the database
                        $cats = get_terms( array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'faq_categories',
                        )); 

                        // loop through the categories
                        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                            // setup the category ID
                            $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
                        ?>

                                <!-- Make a header for the category -->
                        <ul id="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>" class="cd-faq-group">
                            <li class="cd-faq-title">
                                <h2>Questions <?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
                            </li>

                            <?php

                            // create a custom wordpress query

                            query_posts( array(
                                'post_type' => 'faqs',
                                'tax_query' => array( 
                                    array( 
                                        'taxonomy' => 'faq_categories', //or tag or custom taxonomy
                                        'field' => 'slug', 
                                        'terms' => 'for-women'
                                    ) 
                                ) 
                            ));

                            // start the wordpress loop!
                            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <li>
                                <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <div class="cd-faq-content">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div> 
                            </li>

                            <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category 

                            wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>


                        </ul>
                        <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not changing as you iterate through the `$cats` array. Perhaps changing the the value of the 'terms' array to `$cat->slug` would give you better results.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much. You have both provided great insight as to what I was missing. I've resolved it now and this is how I went about solving it taking your suggestions into consideration.

```
<?php

    $cats = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'faq_categories',
            'orderby' => 'term_id',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        )
    ); 

    foreach ($cats as $cat) :
?>


<ul id="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>" class="cd-faq-group">
    <li class="cd-faq-title">
        <h2>Questions <?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
    </li>
<?php

    $questions = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'category_name' => $cat->slug
        )
    );

    $questions = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'faqs',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array( 
            array( 
                'taxonomy' => 'faq_categories',
                'field' => 'slug', 
                'terms' => array($cat->slug),
            )
        ) 
    ));
?>

<?php if ($questions->have_posts()) :  while ($questions->have_posts()) : $questions->the_post();?>

    <li>
        <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="#0"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <div class="cd-faq-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `query_post`, your `tax_query`'s `field` should be `term_id` and your `terms` be assigned to your `$cat_id` variable, instead of a hardcoded term.